# Undefined method for model in Ruby on Rails in Comment-Article application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined-behavior

I am doing basic ruby on rails app and am encountering strange error while am trying to save comment (model Comment) in my article (model Article). Namely i get the error "undefined method title for #Comment:0x000001ce6c353108, i have checked numerous times on stackoverflow and other places but couldn't find the solution.
I can save the articles, but cannot save the Comment which belongs to particular Article, and the error is in the statement `@comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)` which should i think take particular found article and save it, method on @article.comments is used to create and save the comment.
I don't have title anywhere in comment model.

My commentsController looks like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end


    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end

end
```

and show.html looks like below:

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<p><%= @article.body %></p>

<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %></li>


 <li><%= link_to "Delete", article_path(@article),
                  method: :delete,
                  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } 
      %></li>

</ul>


<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>


<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_with model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ] do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

My _form.html looks like:

```
<%= form_with model: article do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
    <% article.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %><br>
    <% article.errors.full_messages_for(:body).each do |message| %>
      <div><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and comment model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article

end
```

I am thinking that maybe in show.html is the error because there is title, but it is related to article so guess i'm wrong.
Thank you very much for any kind of help, i think i am missing something that should perhaps know how to fix.
(i have checked post with similar content but there was title validation in comment model)

Comment: For starters you should really check if `@comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)` actually creates a comment...

Comment: According to this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html it shoudl i guess. It says "We use the create method on @article.comments to create and save the comment. This will automatically link the comment so that it belongs to that particular article."  I will check how else can i create comment..

Comment: The example in the guides is actually flawed. Unless you actually check if the record is created you have no idea if the user passed valid input and you're not actually letting the user know if they didn't do so. Its done correctly further up in the guide when creating the article.

Comment: Thank you, there is no comment.. will find some other correct syntax for creating, didn't know that about guidelines..

Comment: Its basically `if @comment.save; redirect_to @article, notice: 'Comment created'; else; render 'articles/show'; end`.  and use `form_with model: [ @article, @comment || @article.comments.build ] do |form|` so that you don't blank the entire form out. The guide really just brushes over entire complexity of dealing with nested resources that don't have thier own views. The way its set up it just redirects the user back no matter if the comment was created or not which is a terrible UX.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much.. ( @comment = @article.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body)) this also doesn't work, maybe article is not good or something similar..)

Comment: Can you add your comment model to the question?